# For each item in a loop, how would you iterate through and return an item in a different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I have a an array of objects like so:

```
arrOfObjs =
[{type: "flower", egg: "something"},
{type: "flower", egg: "something2"},
{type: "notFlower", egg: "something3"},
{type: "flower", egg: "something4"}]
```

Each object in the array has a 'type'. Whenever a user clicks on an item on the page, then another object is added to the array with type either "flower" or "notFlower"

I have another array like so:

```
allProperties = 
["flower_style_1",
"flower_style_2",
"flower_style_3",
"flower_style_4",
"flower_style_5",
"flower_style_6",
"flower_style_7",
"flower_style_8"]
```

As you can tell it's essentially flower_style_ then a number up to 8.

For each item in arrOfObjs with type = flower, and any new item added, then there should be a return statement where the subject returned is something from the allProperties array.

For example, in arrOfObjs above:

1. For {type: "flower", egg: "something"} => return "flower_style_1".
2. For {type: "flower", egg: "something2"} => return "flower_style_2".
3. Don't return anything for {type: "notFlower", egg: "something3"}
   because it's not of "type": flower.
4. For {type: "flower", egg: "something4"} => return "flower_style_3".
5. etc.

Once all items in allProperties have been returned, then start from the beginning flower_style_1 and return that for each new item in arrOfObjs.

So far, I have the following written which is a foreach loop going through arrOfObjs.

```
    this.arrOfObjs?.forEach(arrItem => {
        if (arrItem.type === 'flower') {
            this.allProperties.forEach(element => {
                return element;
            }
        }
    });
```

However it doesn't work and I think there would be a more efficient way of achieving this. Especially without having an array of flower_style_.......

Would anyone have an idea of how to achieve the above?

Comment: "I want it so that for each item in the arrOfObjs array and any new item added, we return a single item from the allProperties array and with each new object added to arrOfObjs, it returns the next item in allProperties and it cycles through allProperties." - I have having difficulty understanding this paragraph.

Comment: "Once all items in allProperties have been assigned" - your post says you want a value from `allProperties` to be **returned**, not "assigned". Please clarify.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - superficially _it should work_ (but it will work horribly slowly because it has `O(n*m)` time-complexity), my guess is that `arrOfObj` and `allProperties` are _not_ members of `this` but are actually locals. Do you get a runtime error message or anything?

Comment: Also, you have a scope conflict: you're reusing the name `element` for two completely separate variables in a nested closure.

Comment: I've altered it so it makes sense, yes a value from allProperties should be returned. There's no error message and what I mean by 'it doesn't work' is that it just doesn't apply the styles (so each item that the user clicks on is applied a different style in the form of flower_style_....).

Comment: Using `return` inside `forEach` does not do what you what you think it does. You should avoid `forEach` and prefer `for(of)` instead.

Comment: A function can only return 1 value - what do you _actually mean_ when you say "return that for each new item" - that's meaningless.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the return value let say if you get `flower_style_2`

Comment: You can replace your inefficient nested loops with this, btw: `arrOfObjs.filter( e => e.type === 'flower' ).map( ( e, idx ) => allProperties[idx % allProperties.length] )` (this runs in `O(n)` time which is far, far better than `O(n*m)`) - however I think you don't yet understand what it is exactly you want your program to do because you've demonstrated that you don't yet understand what it is to "return" (I hope I'm not sounding condescending, I apologise if I do)

Comment: @Dai That's exactly the same solution I came up with...DITTO

Comment: Apologies I've worded it quite badly, so this function is a vuex getter (or computed value). For each item in the arrOfObjs array, a value from allProperties needs to be returned (so using a return statement). This does only return 1 thing, but it returns 1 thing for each item in arrOfObjs. So as a simple example, say you have 3 animals: Bear, Lion, Turtle. Each animal needs a colour. So We assign Bear the colour white, lion the colour yellow and turtle the colour green. We can think of each item in arrOfObjs as an animal and allProperties as a colour.

Answer (score 0):

```js
      arrOfObjs =
[{type: "flower", egg: "something"},
{type: "flower", egg: "something2"},
{type: "notFlower", egg: "something3"},
{type: "flower", egg: "something4"}]

allProperties = 
["flower_style_1",
"flower_style_2",
"flower_style_3",
"flower_style_4",
"flower_style_5",
"flower_style_6",
"flower_style_7",
"flower_style_8"];


let getArray=[]; 
arrOfObjs?.forEach((arrItem,i) => {
        if (arrItem.type === 'flower') {
            getArray.push(allProperties[getArray.length]);
        }
    });  
    console.log(getArray);
```

Comment: This fails to address the requirement of _then start from the beginning_ in the original question.